# Why Android use separate xmlns for ContraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm little confused about ConstraintLayout in Android. I was learning about it and first thing I get confused about it why android use separate xml namespace for it? `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

ConstraintLayout is part of Layout then why google didn't added it in the old namespace? `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

and why android required to write full qualified name in XML? `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` why not just ConstraintLayout? as RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ConstraintLayout is part of Layout then why google didn't added it in the old namespace?

That is reserved for platform-defined attributes. `ConstraintLayout` is from a library, not from the platform.

> and why android required to write full qualified name in XML? android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout why not just ConstraintLayout?

Android only knows to look in a couple of platform-defined packages for views using the shorthand, bare-class-name-only notation. `android.support.constraint` is from a library, not the platform.

Comment: I was expecting same answer as you did. But why google didn't made it platform specific? I think it could be more easy for developers because it looks like RelativeLayout will be replaced by it.

Comment: @Nothing: "But why google didn't made it platform specific?" -- `ConstraintLayout` was released last year. If they put it in the firmware, it would be in Android 7.0+. Android 7.0+ is on very few devices right now, whereas the `ConstraintLayout` library can be used on apps supporting hundreds of millions of devices. `RelativeLayout` will not be replaced by `ConstraintLayout`, insofar as `RelativeLayout` will be supported indefinitely for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: I'm back with new confusion to confirm that why android not didn't write full qualified name to solve the path? mean suppose I write just ConstraintLayout then the android could add the fully qualified name in background. Why android didn't do that? Just to show that it is Library specific not the platform specific?

Comment: @Nothing: What happens if there are 2+ classes that are named `ConstraintLayout`? How would the conflict be resolved? In general, asking "why did Developer X do Thing Y?" is useless on Stack Overflow. The only one who can answer definitively is Developer X, and Developer X is unlikely to be here answering questions.

Comment: I know it could be difficult to answer, but I was asking that may be there could be something to learn for better design approaches. Any how thanks now Understood.