# Why app namespace doesn't have autocompletion in just one of my Android project layouts?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

When I put "app:" in  main_activity.xml, doesn't work the autocompletion, it only shows 1 option:

```
   appNs
```

But when I do in another xml like fragment_owl.xml, it gives me all the attributes of app namespace.
I have **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto** in both of them

this are my xmls

**activity_main.xml: (that has autocompletion of app namespace attributes)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/holamundo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:text="Hola Mundo"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"
        android:text="GIRAR"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_dice"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat = "@drawable/dice_1"
        />

<!--        android:src="@drawable/dice_1"-->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but in this another one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <fragment

                android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app <- NO AUTOCOMPLETION :(


                />
        </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

I've already try invalite cache and delete or override some folders but nothings seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging i found out the following

Changing your `LinearLayout` to a `ConstraintLayout` solves your problem, but why?

`ConstraintLayout` is from a library (you import it via your build.gradle `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:*.*.*`)

CommonsWare explains it here [android.support.constraint is from a library, not the platform.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958460/13110837)

Taking this into account Android Studio maybe doesnt understand the `app` namespace for layouts that belong to the Android platform like `LinearLayout` as they are part of the `android` namespace.

This is my interpretation, hope it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue here what worked for me

1. Click Blue stack icon (present in top left corner of layout preview) -> Force Refresh Layout

[image]

2. Set Constraints by dragging constraints in Layout preview window once

[image]

Now suggestions should start appearing again.